# Clarifying a proof for $G\mathbf{\pi}=0$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, markov-chains, markov-process

[image]

While following a text on Continuous Time Markov Chains, I came across this proof for $G\mathbf{\pi}=0$. However, I fail to see how they get rid of the summation. Can anyone clarify why that relation is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Informally: equate like powers of $t$.

More formally: differentiate both sides $n$ times at $t=0$.  The  series converges exponentially fast (you may bound $\|\pi G^n\|$ by $\|\pi\| \|G\|^n$ where $\|G\|$ is the operator norm) and so the derivative may be moved inside the infinite sum.

Alternatively: $0$ is an analytic function, and so the only power series that converges to it at every point (note that the series on the right hand side *does* converge) is the series with all terms zero.

Comment: Honestly, the informal explanation is a little brief for my understanding, the formal explanation is a little over my head, and I don't see why the alternative is true. Sorry, I'm not extremely familiar with series which is probably where my confusion stems from. Wouldn't the power series for cosine converge to 0?

Comment: @discuit: When I said "converge" I meant pointwise convergence of functions.  The power series for cosine doesn't converge to the 0 *function*.  In this case the series converges to 0 for every $t$.